# Use numpy to get the positions of all objects in 3D space relative to one another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, array-broadcasting

I want get the differences between all permutations of pairs of *vectors* in a numpy array.

In my specific use case these vectors are the 3D position vectors of a list of objects.

So, if I have an array `r = [r1, r2, r3]` where `r1`, `r2` and `r3` are 3-dimensional vectors, I want the following:

```
[[r1-r1 r1-r2 r1-r3]
 [r2-r1 r2-r2 r2-r3]
 [r3-r1 r3-r2 r3-r3]]
```

Where the `-` op is applied element-wise to the vectors.

Basically, the vector equivalent of this:

```
>>> scalars = np.arange(3)
>>> print(scalars)
[0 1 2]

>>> result = np.subtract.outer(scalars, scalars)
>>> print(result)
[[ 0 -1 -2]
 [ 1  0 -1]
 [ 2  1  0]]
```

However, the `outer` function seems to flatten my array of vectors before subtraction and then reshapes it. For example:

```
>>> vectors = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) # Two 3-dimensional vectors
>>> print(vectors)
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]

>>> results = np.subtract.outer(vectors, vectors)
>>> print(results.shape)
(2, 3, 2, 3)
```

The result that I'm expecting is:

```
>>> print(result)
[[[ 0  0  0]
  [-3 -3 -3]]
 [[ 3  3  3]
  [ 0  0  0]]]

>>> print(result.shape)
(2, 2, 3)
```

Can I achieve the above without iterating over the array?

Comment: If this is just a question to learn, forget the following comment. But if you really need to calculate efficiently all possible distances and you can use scipy, checkout `pdist`: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is almost always [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
>>> r = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
>>> r[:, None] - r
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],
        [-3, -3, -3]],

       [[ 3,  3,  3],
        [ 0,  0,  0]]])
```

That `None` in the indexing is the same as `np.newaxis`, and adds a dimension of size 1 to the shape of the array. So you are subtracting from an array of shape `(2, 1, 3)` an array with shape `(2, 3)`, which gets converted by broadcasting to `(1, 2, 3)`, and the end result is your desired `(2, 2, 3)` array. While broadcasting is conceptually similar to using `np.tile` or `np.repeat`, it is much more efficient, as it avoids creating expanded copies of the original arrays.

Comment: Excellent. I was hoping to see something which uses broadcasting correctly. I'm still wrapping my head around broadcasting n-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

An (almost) pure Python way to do a "pair-wise outer subtraction" of vectors `r` would be as follows:

```py
np.array(map(operator.sub, *zip(*product(r, r)))).reshape((2, 2, -1))
```

So you basically can use the `product` function to get all possible pairs of list items, un`zip` them to get two separate lists and `map` them to the subtraction `operator`. Finally you can `reshape` it as usual.

**Step-by-step:**

Here is a step-by-step example with all required libraries and outputs of intermediate results:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import operator

r = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

print "Vectors:\n", r
print "Product:\n", list(product(r, r))
print "Zipped:\n", zip(*product(r, r))
print "Mapped:\n", map(operator.sub, *zip(*product(r, r)))
print "Reshaped:\n", np.array(map(operator.sub, *zip(*product(r, r)))).reshape((2, 2, -1))
```

Output:

```
Vectors:
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
Product:
[(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2])), (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5])), (array([3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 2])), (array([3, 4, 5]), array([3, 4, 5]))]
Zipped:
[(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([3, 4, 5])), (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5]))]
Mapped:
[array([0, 0, 0]), array([-3, -3, -3]), array([3, 3, 3]), array([0, 0, 0])]
Reshaped:
[[[ 0  0  0]
  [-3 -3 -3]]

 [[ 3  3  3]
  [ 0  0  0]]]
```

(Note that I need to switch the dimensions `2` and `3` in order to create your example array.)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the 2 and 3 in my code. I was hoping for something more "numpy-ish". I realize this is probably premature optimization, but it seems like a numeric library such as numpy should also have the benefit of more readable code in this case. Your array-fu is much stronger than mine - could you suggest improvements to the answer which I just added?

Answer (score 3):

(Answering my own question here)

Here is an approach using Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2
r = np.arange(N * 3).reshape(N, 3)

left = np.tile(r, N).reshape(N, N, 3)
right = np.transpose(left, axes=[1, 0, 2])

result = left - right
print result
```

This seems to work for any 2D array where the inner dimension has size 3, but I did it mostly by trial and error, so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Oh, that's a good approach. Somehow I tried to avoid NumPy, but I'm not sure why! I'd just write that one line a bit more general as ```left = np.tile(r, len(r)).reshape(len(r), len(r), -1)```. (The ```-1``` tells ```reshape``` to compute that dimension itself.)